# Custom result page upon submitting search form

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm running in circle, i'm trying to run a query from a custom search form and to display the result on a specific custom page.

I've created a custom search page called `search-custom.php` and i've registered it.
Now I don't understand why when I submit my seachform i'm getting a 404 error.

This is my searchform currently, upon submitting the form, the url path seems right, am I missing something?

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url().'/search-custom' ); ?>" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" value="qcm" name="post_type">
<button type="submit"><span class="mr-2">Go</button>
</form>
```

I don't want to redirect it from the function.php file I need this current format. Thanks in advance for your lights.

Comment: does `home_url()` produce a trailing slash?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to change the `action` of your form to the name of your template file. Inside of your search-custom.php there is:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="qcm" name="post_type">
    <button type="submit"><span class="mr-2">Go</button>
</form>
```

With this template file having set, you can use it in your page template (the page you want the form to display, or maybe in a sidebar or something) with:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'search', 'custom' ); ?>
```

The default wordpress search template will be used to output the results.

If you want to use a different template file for the results, you can put this in the functions.php file of your theme and change the results page (i.e. search-results-custom.php):

```
add_action('template_include', 'search_custom_template');

function search_custom_template( $template ) {
  if ( isset( $_REQUEST['search'] ) && is_search() ) {
     $temp = locate_template('search-results-custom.php');
     if ( ! empty($temp) ) {
         $template = $temp;
     }
  }
  return $template;
}
```

---

**Multiple search results pages using different forms**

If you want to set a value in your form, and using that to get to specific result pages:

1. Open the search.php file of your theme, make a copy for safety and replace the whole content of the file with the following code:

   ```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
        if($type == 'qcm') {
            load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search-custom.php');
        } elseif($type == 'another') {
            load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search-another.php');
        }
    }
    ?>
   ```

In this code we check what value is set for the field with the name `post_type`. In your question, you have set the value of `qcm`. When the field has this value on submit, you will load the `search-custom.php`. If you have other forms with other values, you can just add an `elseif` and load another search results template.

If you want to use another hidden input for checking the value, you can simply create one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my-hidden-info" value="value-to-check" />
```

As you see, this way you can edit a value inside of your form and get different search results pages for the specific values. The action of the form is not changed and you will always use the `search.php` file. You just add other templates, which you are loading inside of this file in the `if and elseif`. So you get multiple search results pages using different forms.

Comment: So there is no alternative to do it from the form itself?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the results page of the search by only adding the target url in the action of the form?

Comment: Yes exactly @rank

Comment: I edited my answer, I think I now got your question the right way.

Comment: Hey @rank, thanks for the answer, this is actually a pretty good idea, will try it out